# Parsing a non-XML document with Nokogiri when the node names are/contain integers

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, rubygems, nokogiri

When I run:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<-EOXML
<pajamas>
  <bananas>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>
    <1>bar</1>
  </bananas>
</pajamas>
EOXML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc.at('/pajamas/bananas/foo')
puts doc.at('/pajamas/bananas/bar')
puts doc.at('/pajamas/bananas/1')
```

I get an `ERROR: Invalid expression: /pajamas/bananas/1 (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)`

Is this a case of Nokogiri not liking ints as node names and/or is there a work around?

Looking at the documentation, I did not see a workaround to this. Removing the last line eliminates the error and prints the first two nodes as expected.

Comment: That isn't an XML document, so you can't parse it using an XML parser. Element names can't start with a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XML element with a name that starts with a number is invalid XML.

XML elements must follow these naming rules:

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Names cannot contain spaces Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

You're trying to parse invalid XML with a XML parser, it's just not going to work.  If you're really getting `<1>` as a tag and can't control that somehow, I'd suggest replacing the tags using a regex before getting to nokogiri.

Comment: [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name) *NameStartChar must meet this definition:* `":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]`

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, I will hit it with a regex first. Cheers!